# Field-level validation for DRF HiddenField in update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the correct way to do field-level validation on DRF `serializers.HiddenField()` ?
What I tried (Assuming field name is x):

- Adding a `validate_x()` method to the serializer class. This method is not being called in partial update action (HTTP PATCH).
- Trying to validate it in `validate(self, data)` method. It does not exist in data dictionary.
- Tried to create a validator and pass it to validators field parameter but they are not called.

---

### What is the correct way to add custom validation for this in partial update? I'm using DRF v3.12.4

Note: I want the field to be hidden from request body definition and still be able to validate and include the field in the serializer.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `validators` argument in the serializer field? Like `HiddenSerializers(validators=[function1, function2])`. Are they triggered?

Comment: @JordanKowal Yes, I tried. They are not called.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to validate it? This field is not provided by the user, and therefore shouldnt need validation.

In the DRF documentation, it is mentionned as:

> A field class that does not take a value based on user input, but instead takes its value from a default value or callable.

And they also talk about its validation:

> Using HiddenField. This field will be present in validated_data but will not be used in the serializer output representation.

You could however perform special/conditional actions in the `create` or `update` method or your serializer, as you have access to `validated_data`, where the field will be accessible

See [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield) and [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults)

Comment: I do think it should be validated. What if we need to validate the automated value ? Example: Maybe we automate a date but don't allow weekends. The automated value can be validated with other fields that the user can input too.